# Passing arrays to functions! Confusions! in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, function

Example array:

```
int hourlyTemperatures[ 24 ];
```

So in function call we write  the array name and its size!

```
modifyArray( hourlyTemperatures, 24 )
```

we know the above mentioned is the right way to pass array to function!

but in this code below I see we are calling mean function and passing array without giving its element size like `mean (response);`

So my question is which one is correct? Passing array with its element size or just passing array with it’s name? And why the two method is used?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 99

void mean(const unsigned int answer[]);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int response [SIZE] =
    {6,7,8,9,8,7,8,9,8,9,7,8,9,5,9,8,7,8,7,8,6,7,8,9,3,9,
     8,7,8,7,7,8,9,8,9,8,9,7,8,9,6,7,8,7,8,7,9,8,9,2,7,8,
     9,8,9,8,9,7,5,3,5,6,7,2,5,3,9,4,6,4,7,8,9,6,8,7,8,9,
     7,8,7,4,4,2,5,3,8,7,5,6,4,5,6,1,6,5,7,8,7
    };

    mean (response);
}

void mean (const unsigned int answer[])
{
    size_t j;
    unsigned int total = 0;

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", "********", "Mean", "********");

    // total response values
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j){
        total += answer[j];
    }

    printf ("The mean is the average value of the data items!\n"
           "The mean is the equal to the total of all data items\n"
           "divided by the number of data items (%u)\n\n", SIZE);

    printf("The mean value for this run is: %u / %u = %.4f\n\n", total, SIZE, (double)total/SIZE );

}
```

Comment: The way it's written, `mean` only works because the size is defined as a macro (it would work as a global as well). If you only ever intend to allow a function to take an input of exactly one size, defined at compile time, that technically _works_, but...

Comment: I'm new at programming! Can you please tell me in details and clearly? I don't know what is macro!

Comment: You can search google or stackoverflow to learn what a macro is in C.

Comment: You can't pass arrays to functions in C. You can only pass pointers to functions, and those pointers can point to the first elements of arrays.

Comment: `modifyArray( hourlyTemperatures, 24 )` passes *two things* to the function: 1) a pointer to the first element of hourlyTemperatures, and 2) the number 24.

Comment: I would make the number of elements have a different argument for its self so it's more portable code as Size is a predefined Marco in **your** code.  Or even better use a vector library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call `modifyArray(hourlyTemperatures, 24)` passes a pointer to the first `int` stored in the array `hourlyTemperatures[]`, so the function knows where to find the first value, and the `int` 24, so the function knows how big the array is to avoid walking off the end of the array.

The function call `mean(response)` passes a pointer to the first `unsigned int` stored in the array `response[]`, but the function needs another way to know how large the array is, since no further information is passed by the caller.

The preprocessor directive `#define SIZE 99` is used when you compile the program, and any occurrence of the characters 'SIZE' is replaced with the characters '99' in the source before the actual compilation, so the function is interpreted with the line:

```
for (j = 0; j < 99; ++j) {...
```

In this way the `mean()` function knows how large the array is. Instead of using the `#define`, you could also put the line:

```
int size = 99;
```

before the function definitions. This would make `size` a global variable visible in any function below it, so you could write:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) {...
```

But, since global variables are generally a bad thing, you should usually pick the first method, explicitly passing the size of the array to the function that processes the array.

So, to recap:

1) It is usually best to pass the size of the array explicitly to the processing function: `modifyArray(hourlyTemperatures, 24)`. This way you always know what size the array is, and you can work with arrays of different sizes: `modifyArray(hourlyTemperatures, 25)`, for example, if you have added a temperature measurement.

2) You can define a constant to store the size of the array, which is then used in the array processing function: `#define SIZE 99`. One downside of this is that if you want to work with an array with 100 elements, you have to change the source code so that `#define SIZE 100`, and then recompile.

3) You can declare a global variable to store the size of the array, and use the global variable in the array processing function. The global variable is accessible to any function below the declaration in the source file. This method is error-prone: another function might inadvertently change the value of `size`, giving you a nasty surprise when you call `mean()`.

One last thing-- a string is an array of `char`s, but not just any old array of `char`s: it must be null-terminated. This means that the last character of a string must be '\0'. Functions that process strings don't need to know the size of the strings (even though a string is an array), because that information is implicit in a string. You can count the number of characters before the '\0' (or just use `strlen()`), or just process characters sequentially until you reach the end.

Comment: If I write int size = 99; though I'm not passing the array size to function mean() then how come function mean() knows the size of the array?

Comment: Because if you declare `int size` before defining any functions (i.e, before `main()` and `mean()`) the variable `size` is available to use inside of those functions. It is global. The function `mean` can use `size` just as if it had been passed in through a function call. But again, this is generally a bad idea, because any change to the global variable affects all of the functions that use it. You should read up on variable scope, linkage, and storage duration to understand this better.